# Clone Form using jQuery with add and remove elements conditions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, dynamic

So, I would like to clone my select-option form, and when it's already meet the criteria (e.g. in this case the user choose **'THEN'** operator) then the form will show a fixed content (Risk - High), hiding specific link (Add More) and showing the Submit button.

What's troubling me is, my code only work only for the first form only when I pick the operator. What I wanted is, I want it to be executed on every last form added.

For example I need an output such this:

> IF age is old AND ldl is high AND hdl is low AND sistolic is high THEN
>   risk is high

Here's my Code:

```js
function rule(id_counter) {
  if (id_counter != 0) {
    var abc = $('#var_name' + id_counter).val();
  } else {
    var abc = $('#var_name').val();
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: 'search_coll.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
      selected_item: abc
    },
    success: function(response) {
      if (id_counter != 0) {
        $('#var_name' + id_counter).html(response);
      } else {
        $('#var_name').html(response);
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log('Request failed.')
    }
  });
};
$(document).ready(function() {
  var count = 1;
  $('#clone').click(function() {
    var ab = $('#tobecloned').clone();
    ab.find('select').attr('id', function(i, val) {
      return val + count;
    });
    ab.find('.js_variable').attr('onChange', function(i, val) {
      return "rule("+ count +")";
    });

    $('#tab').append(ab);
    count++;
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="tab">
    <tr id="tobecloned">
      <td>
        <select name="id_var[]" id="var_name" class="js_variable" onChange="rule(0)">
          <option>Choose Variable</option>
          <?php include "../connect.php"; $query_v=m ysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * from variables ORDER BY id_var"); while($result_v=mysqli_fetch_array($query_v, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $result_v['id_var'];?>">
            <?php echo $result_v[ 'var_name'];?>
          </option>
          <?php } ?>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="coll_name">
          <option>Choose Collection</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="operator">
          <option>Choose Operator</option>
          <option value="AND">AND</option>
          <option value="THEN">THEN</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="showifthen">
      <!-- i want to show this, if the user choose THEN from the last appended/cloned select operator -->
      <td>
        <select name="var_name">
          <option>Risk</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="coll_name">
          <option>High</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <a href="#" id="clone">Add More</a> 
  <!-- this should be hidden if user choose THEN -->
  <a type="submit" id="hideatfirst" hidden>Submit</a> 
  <!-- i want this to be hidden at first, and shown when user choose THEN from the last appended/cloned select operator -->

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks before

Comment: @OP, share the parsed HTML..Instead of `<?php..`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things amiss here.

The selects don't all have IDs, so the loop that tries to update them would set them to `NaN`.

However, you are using `.attr('id')` on a collection, which returns only the first ID anyway, not all of them.

To operate on each element in turn, use `.each()` like this:

```
ab.find('select').each(function() {
  var el = $(this)
  el.attr('id', el.attr('id') + count)
});
```

In order to take action when the select value is changed, you need to assign it an on change handler with `.change()`, something like

```
$('#operator').change(function() {
  operatorSelect($(this))
})
```

You will have to assign the change handler separately for each select as you clone them, and you probably want to disable each previous operator select so there is no ambiguity about which one is changed.

I found this to be a fun little diversion, so I put together a quick fiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/xosqw00p/

Comment: ah, anyway, making the options disabled won't let me post the value. So, I keep it enabled :)